# How to add sps pps (read from mp4 file) information to every IDR frame

Tags: ios, encoding, video-streaming, h.264, mp4

I want gengrate video streaming from camera so that the other point can show video in real time.
I need hardware encoding so this may works to me

http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2013/02/20/iOS-Video-Encoding.html

The problem is this demo is just read mp4 file data and transport with rtsp the sps pps information was in moov type box of mp4 file

we have our own transport Protocol so I can not use rtsp transport protocal

I can find the sps and pps information and how can I add the sps and pps to every IDR frame so that the other point can decode the frame successfully

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

SPS and PPS is also just a NAL like your IDR, P or B frame. You should be able to insert it directly into your stream without causing issues.

Comment: Thanks and I have insert it at the head of the stream and the other point only can decode several frames . should I insert it into stream every IDR frame appears or just insert at the head of the stream @Sebastian Annies

Comment: Typically SPS/PPS is only at the beginning of the stream. You only send new SPS/PPS if the decoder settings are changed within the stream.

Comment: I have solve my problem .The other point can show the video from my iphone camera in real time .first insert the sps pps frame at the head of the stream and then used 00 00 00 01 separate every frame read from mp4 file